# How to open new page after a successful login GWT Java

Tags: java, asynchronous, gwt, authentication

I'm making a GWT application that requires users to log in. If username and password are correct, then they are allowed to use the application.

What needs to be implemented in the `onSuccess()` method to make this possible ?

Thanks in advance.

```
DBConnectionAsync rpcService = (DBConnectionAsync) GWT.create(DBConnection.class);
    ServiceDefTarget target = (ServiceDefTarget) rpcService;
    String moduleRelativeURL = GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "DBConnectionImpl";
    target.setServiceEntryPoint(moduleRelativeURL);

    rpcService.authenticateUser("admin", "admin", new AsyncCallback<User>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(User result) {
            // What to do here to open or redirect the user to a new page ?

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            // Failure

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way of doing this would be to fire an event to the eventbus of you application and then catch this event in the main controller of your application, which would trigger the opening of the right page.

This two pages should explain everything you possibly need to know to do this:

- [Everything about the architecture GWT MVP](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/mvp-architecture.html)
- [Everything about activity and places (navigation and history)](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html)

Just as if you need more information.

Comment: I think the second link is the most relevant for you. But the first one might help you understand how things work too.

Answer (score 0):

From onSuccess you can call a method which will be defined in a corresponding presenter and from that method you can fire an event which will allow user to enter into your application only on successful authentication .